# Android Webview Video - net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: html, android-studio, video, webview

I am developing an Excel Tutorials app using Android Studio in which I am creating the lessons using html. In each lesson, there is a step-by-step instruction and video instructions. Now, when I am running my Application using real device. It doesn't shows only the text, not the video. However, when I am testing the html in laptop using Google Chrome, its working fine. Now what should I do?

I have seen many questions like this but the answers are of how to show the video. But in my html there is text also.

My code of html :

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O0pcJdKQt1ZYf8BTl1WNzgyyo00pnoD5/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

My Android Studio Code :

```
public class Lessons_Content extends AppCompatActivity {

ActionBar lessontexttoolbar;
WebView lessoncontent;
Integer lessoninteger;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_lessons);

    lessontexttoolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (lessontexttoolbar != null) {
        lessontexttoolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    lessoncontent = findViewById(R.id.lesson_content);
    lessoncontent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    lessoncontent.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    lessoncontent.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        lessoncontent.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    }
    lessoncontent.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    lessoninteger = getIntent().getIntExtra("lessonextra", 0);
    
    if (lessoninteger == 0) {
        lessoncontent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});
        lessoncontent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String html = "<iframe src=\"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O0pcJdKQt1ZYf8BTl1WNzgyyo00pnoD5/preview\" width=640 height=480 allowfullscreen=true></iframe>\n";
        lessoncontent.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }

}
```

Output :

Webpage not available.

The Webpage at 'url' cannot be loaded because :

net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Screenshot after implementing the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67789248/15940811).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this One :

```
WebView urlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
urlWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O0pcJdKQt1ZYf8BTl1WNzgyyo00pnoD5/preview");


public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {



    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

Comment: Again thank you very much for your great response. I tried implementing your code. However, its saying to sign in to Google. Please see my edited question. I have given the screenshot how it is showing.

Comment: Sorry for my late response but I wanted to ask that what I have to make public? Because everything in my file is public...

Comment: make the file public ....... your file is not public .

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand correctly. Are you saying to change protected void onCreate into public void onCreate?

Comment: the file on Google Drive ....... make that file public

Answer (score 0):

Try Enabling JavaScript to webView, using web settings before loading.

`WebSettings webSettings = webv.getSettings();`
`webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: Thank you for your great response. I tried this once, still not working. The same message is showing.

Comment: In start of String html = "<iframe src=\"https://d....try Removing '\'............
String html = "<iframe src=\"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O0pcJdKQt1ZYf8BTl1WNzgyyo00pnoD5/preview\" width=640 height=480 allowfullscreen=true></iframe>\n";